# How to prevent android keyboard from hiding if clicked on send button- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to develop an online web-app for chatting. In the page, I have an input field and a send button on right side of it.

In android mobile phones when I enter some text and when clicking on send button (i.e on right side of input) the keyboard gets dismiss but when I press enter through the keyboard, the keyboard doesn't dismiss and also message send successfully.

How can I prevent disappearing of the keyboard if send button is clicked?

This is not how to hide keyboard but prevent automatic hiding when pressed button on web page.

Comment: @imvain2 this is not how to hide keyboard but stop automatic hiding when pressed button on page, this can't be duplicate of what you mentioned.

Comment: I apologize I misunderstood. Is your button submitting the form or triggering ajax?

Comment: @imvain2 I am using WebSockets, button is triggering `WebSocke.send`,and also for enter button of keyboard `if (e.keyCode === 13) {
          document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
      }`

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the button event code block assign focus to the input.

```
document.getElementById("sendButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
    // your code
    document.getElementById("myTextField").focus();
 });
```